# Scalas language package unavailable?

Tags: scala, import, package

It seems as if my scala installation does not contain a rather fundamental package, [scala.language](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.language$):

```
scala> import language._
<console>:7: error: not found: value language
       import language._
              ^

scala> import scala.language._
<console>:7: error: object language is not a member of package scala
       import scala.language._
```

I've re-installed scala from my Linux repositores (I'm running LMDE 2 "Betsy"), yet I've had no luck. It is unclear to me how exactly I can just download the respective jar, place it somewhere in my system and have the import work.

Here are specs about my system and java/scala installation that might be of use:

```
jasonfil@hp ~ $ cat /etc/debian_version
8.1
jasonfil@hp ~ $ uname -r
3.16.0-4-amd64
jasonfil@hp ~ $ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
jasonfil@hp ~ $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-1~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
jasonfil@hp ~ $ echo $CLASSPATH
/home/jasonfil/AtomicScala/examples:/usr/share/java
```

Comment: `language` package does not seem to be supported in scala 2.9.2. you should install newer scala version.
 http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/

Comment: You were right. Marking this solved. Thanks.

Comment: The doc you linked to is the *nightly* generated doc of the very latest bleeding edge checkout of the development branch. In general, it should be expected that not everything you find there will apply to a released version, especially not one as old as the one you are using. The `scala.language` specifically, is well-known to have been introduced in 2.10 as a means of both "stratifying" the language for different levels of developer expertise, and as a means of gradually making backwards-compatible changes or removals, or experimental additions to the language.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as @ymonad said, this appeared to be a question of trusting the language's source more than the Debian repo version. Marking this solved. Thanks.